# Why is the SimpleDateFormat outputting the wrong time for 12pm

Tags: android

I'm developing a application that converts a date and time into a long int and saves it to a database. I then can edit that date and time by retrieving it from the database, by which it converts the long int back into the separate date and time so that they can be modified.

The problem I have though, is, when I save 12:00pm into the database and I retrieve it, it comes backs as 00:00am I don't don't why this is. It only happens when I save 12:00pm. For example, if I was to save 00:00am it comes back as 00:00am or any other time for that matter whether it's am or pm, but 12:00pm seems to never come back as 12:00pm.

Heres the part of the code that retrieves the long int from the database and converts it into a date

```
long longDate = reminder.getLong(db.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RDB.KEY_DT));  //retrieve long value 

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 

Date date = new Date(longDate); //convert long value to date

String dateToString = formatter.format(date); //convert date to string
```

Help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is causing because your database is saving 12:00 pm as 00:00 am, since the database is taking the time in 24-hr format, Change,

```
SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

Needed to be:

SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```